# What is the function of "Intent.ACTION_PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED"?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to know the exact functionality of `Intent.ACTION_PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED`. Currently, my requirement is to complete the task before the completion of booting of the device, i.e. before the call of `Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`.
Can anyone guide me on how to proceed to fulfill the requirement? Any help in this regard will be well appreciated.

Comment: Here is the cross-post and discussion on android-developers: https://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/e852941aace768c3

Answer (score -2, accepted):

There is no such action as ACTION_PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED. I think that you normally can't fill your requirement. May be there is some mechanism for system signed apps to do that.

Comment: Hi Vladimir Ivanov, thanks for the reply. Currently, my task is to display some animation on the customized LockScreen before the completion of the BOOT of the device. Is it possible? or I have to display animation only after the bootup of device. Currently, I am working on ICS source.

Comment: ActivityManagerService.java     public void systemReady(final Runnable goingCallback) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (mSystemReady) {
                if (goingCallback != null) goingCallback.run();
                return;
            }
            
            // Check to see if there are any update receivers to run.
            if (!mDidUpdate) {
                if (mWaitingUpdate) {
                    return;
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED);
                List<ResolveInfo> ris = null;
                try {

Answer (score 3):

ACTION_PRE_BOOT_COMPLETED is sended in ActivityManagerService.java::systemReady.

But to received it, the uid of your application must be system(1000).

```
                for (int i=ris.size()-1; i>=0; i--) {
                    if ((ris.get(i).activityInfo.applicationInfo.flags
                            &ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
                        ris.remove(i);
                    }
                }
```

Further more, this broadcast could only be received once in each upgrade( not very sure here, maybe should be each wipe data).

Note code below, if the target is in lastDoneReceivers, it will be removed.

```
                ArrayList<ComponentName> lastDoneReceivers = readLastDonePreBootReceivers();

                final ArrayList<ComponentName> doneReceivers = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
                for (int i=0; i<ris.size(); i++) {
                    ActivityInfo ai = ris.get(i).activityInfo;
                    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(ai.packageName, ai.name);
                    if (lastDoneReceivers.contains(comp)) {
                        ris.remove(i);
                        i--;
                    }
                }
```

lastDoneReceivers is read from file /data/system/called_pre_boots.dat.

```
private static File getCalledPreBootReceiversFile() {
    File dataDir = Environment.getDataDirectory();
    File systemDir = new File(dataDir, "system");
    File fname = new File(systemDir, "called_pre_boots.dat");
    return fname;
}

static final int LAST_DONE_VERSION = 10000;

private static ArrayList<ComponentName> readLastDonePreBootReceivers() {
    ArrayList<ComponentName> lastDoneReceivers = new ArrayList<ComponentName>();
    File file = getCalledPreBootReceiversFile();
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fis, 2048));
        int fvers = dis.readInt();
        if (fvers == LAST_DONE_VERSION) {
            String vers = dis.readUTF();
            String codename = dis.readUTF();
            String build = dis.readUTF();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals(vers)
                    && android.os.Build.VERSION.CODENAME.equals(codename)
                    && android.os.Build.VERSION.INCREMENTAL.equals(build)) {
                int num = dis.readInt();
                while (num > 0) {
                    num--;
                    String pkg = dis.readUTF();
                    String cls = dis.readUTF();
                    lastDoneReceivers.add(new ComponentName(pkg, cls));
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Slog.w(TAG, "Failure reading last done pre-boot receivers", e);
    } finally {
        if (fis != null) {
            try {
                fis.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return lastDoneReceivers;
}
```